# unable to download images as bytes from telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to download the images from telegram as bytes or base64 instead of image. I don't know if there is a way to do it. I went through the documentation and tried something as shown below but it did not work.

```
channels = ['channel_name']
async with TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash) as client:    
    ## looping through channels in telegram
    for channel in channels:
        try:
            async with client.takeout() as takeout:
                async for message in takeout.iter_messages(channel,  wait_time=0):
                    try:
                        # await client.download_media(message.media, temp_folder+channel+str(message.id))
                        print(message.media)
                        data = await client.download_file(
                            message.media,
                            bytes,
                            progress_callback=callback
                        )                      

                        image = mpimg.imread(io.BytesIO(data), format='JPEG')
                        plt.imshow(image)
                    except FileReferenceExpiredError:
                        print('A FileReferenceExpiredError Exception occured')
        except errors.TakeoutInitDelayError as e:
            print('Must wait', e.seconds, 'before takeout')
```

It prints the message first and then show the error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\TEMP\hkay\Temp\ipykernel_79040\2965379116.py in <module>
     53                         # await client.download_media(message.media, temp_folder+channel+str(message.id))
     54                         print(message.media)
---> 55                         data = await client.download_file(
     56                             message,
     57                             bytes,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\downloads.py in download_file(self, input_location, file, part_size_kb, file_size, progress_callback, dc_id, key, iv)
    490                 print(data[:16])
    491         """
--> 492         return await self._download_file(
    493             input_location,
    494             file,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\downloads.py in _download_file(self, input_location, file, part_size_kb, file_size, progress_callback, dc_id, key, iv, msg_data)
    547 
    548                 if progress_callback:
--> 549                     r = progress_callback(f.tell(), file_size)
    550                     if inspect.isawaitable(r):
    551                         await r

D:\TEMP\hkay\Temp\ipykernel_79040\1493750919.py in callback(current, total, channel_name)
     33 def callback(current, total, channel_name=channel):
     34     print('Downloaded from',channel,'-', 'message_id:', message.id, ' ', current, 'out of', total,
---> 35           'bytes: {:.2%}'.format(current / total))
     36 
     37 # Connect to API with Client

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

**Edit 1:**

After removing the progress_callback, here is what I am seeing.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\utils.py in _get_file_info(location)
    800     try:
--> 801         if location.SUBCLASS_OF_ID == 0x1523d462:
    802             return _FileInfo(None, location, None)  # crc32(b'InputFileLocation'):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SUBCLASS_OF_ID'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\TEMP\hkhan\Temp\ipykernel_79040\1631659142.py in <module>
     53                         #await client.download_media(message.media, temp_folder+channel+str(message.id))
     54 
---> 55                         data = await client.download_file(message.media
     56                                                           ,bytes
     57                                                          )                      

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\downloads.py in download_file(self, input_location, file, part_size_kb, file_size, progress_callback, dc_id, key, iv)
    490                 print(data[:16])
    491         """
--> 492         return await self._download_file(
    493             input_location,
    494             file,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\downloads.py in _download_file(self, input_location, file, part_size_kb, file_size, progress_callback, dc_id, key, iv, msg_data)
    538 
    539         try:
--> 540             async for chunk in self._iter_download(
    541                     input_location, request_size=part_size, dc_id=dc_id, msg_data=msg_data):
    542                 if iv and key:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\client\downloads.py in _iter_download(self, file, offset, stride, limit, chunk_size, request_size, file_size, dc_id, msg_data)
    680             msg_data: tuple = None
    681     ):
--> 682         info = utils._get_file_info(file)
    683         if info.dc_id is not None:
    684             dc_id = info.dc_id

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\utils.py in _get_file_info(location)
    802             return _FileInfo(None, location, None)  # crc32(b'InputFileLocation'):
    803     except AttributeError:
--> 804         _raise_cast_fail(location, 'InputFileLocation')
    805 
    806     if isinstance(location, types.Message):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\telethon\utils.py in _raise_cast_fail(entity, target)
    136 
    137 def _raise_cast_fail(entity, target):
--> 138     raise TypeError('Cannot cast {} to any kind of {}.'.format(
    139         type(entity).__name__, target))
    140 

TypeError: Cannot cast NoneType to any kind of InputFileLocation.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `progress_callback`. `total` is `None` because the maximum file size is not known. Simply removing it, if you don't need it, should work. Otherwise, check that `total` is not none inside the callback, or explicitly pass a size to the download method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed the progress_callback and it prompted a different error. I am modifying it in my code.

Comment: You are trying to download every message, even those that have no media, which will obviously fail.